# Make predictions with a trained model on Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm very new to programming and machine learning but I've been trying to create a prediction model to tag product reviews. I found the following model:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
# the Naive Bayes model
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
# function to split the data for cross-validation
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
# function for transforming documents into counts
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
# function for encoding categories
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

dataset = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')

def normalize_text(s):
    s = s.lower()

    # remove punctuation that is not word-internal (e.g., hyphens, apostrophes)
    s = re.sub('\s\W',' ',s)
    s = re.sub('\W\s',' ',s)

    # make sure we didn't introduce any double spaces
    s = re.sub('\s+',' ',s)

    return s

dataset['TEXT'] = [normalize_text(s) for s in dataset['texto']]

# pull the data into vectors
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
x = vectorizer.fit_transform(dataset['TEXT'])

encoder = LabelEncoder()
y = encoder.fit_transform(dataset['codigo'])

# split into train and test sets
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2)

nb = MultinomialNB()
nb.fit(x_train, y_train)

y_predicted = nb.predict(x_test)
```

So far so good. But then, I tried to use that trained model to predict another set of data like this:

```
#new data
test = pd.read_csv('testset.csv')
test['TEXT'] = [normalize_text(s) for s in test['respostas']]

# pull the data into vectors
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
classes = vectorizer.fit_transform(test['TEXT'])

classificacao = nb.predict(classes)
```

However, I got a "ValueError: dimension mismatch"

I'm not sure how to do this second step, which is using the model to predict the category of a fresh data set.

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: what is `classes` shape ? and what's `x_test` shape?

Comment: `classes` shape is (50,201) and `x_test` shape is (126, 1985)

Comment: Do you mean to call `fit_transform` on the vectorizer in your test code? Shouldn't you only call `vectorizer.transform(test['TEXT'])` once you've called a `fit` command on your training data?